# How to target & alter child element by tag with only the parent div id?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs, parent-child, getelementsbytagname

Using regular JavaScript (or *prototype)*, I'm trying to alter the href attribute of the first and only anchor tag within a div to include a query string at the end with windows.location.search. The div has an id, while the anchor is classless and id-less. I've seen similar code elsewhere, but its not quite right.

What I have so far is below:

```
var divTag =  document.getElementById("DivId").getElementsByTagName("a");
for(i = 0; i < divTag.length; i++){
    divTags[i].href = "myUrl"+window.location.search;
}
```

The actual html code I"m tryin to work on:

```
<div id="DivId">
     <a href="OldHref">
          <img/>
     </a>
</div>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Make sure the elements exist when you run the code (so either put the script at the end of `body`, or execute it on the `load` event).

Comment: Thanks for the advice Felix. I'll put it to good use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the variable as `divTag` but set the attribute as `divTags`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is largely correct.  You just made a typo:

`divTags[i].href = "myUrl"+window.location.search;`

Should be:

`divTag[i].href = "myUrl"+window.location.search;`

Singular instead of plural.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I've correct my typo, but I've just realized I have another problem.

Comment: @SFox No problem. Why don't you describe your new problem?

Comment: The class-less & id-less anchor tag within the parent div I'm targeting is buried within a series of another divs, similar to the following: 

<body>
    <div id=container>
        <div id=content>
            <div id=fullcontent>
                <div id=Golf>
                    <div id=topcol>
                        <div id=livegolf>
                            <div id=TargetDiV>
                                <a> href="OldHref"</a>

The code works flawlessly when its not buried in the page, so how do I target my div that's buried within other divs?

Comment: The code from the question should happily search through the entire document for your div with id "DivId" and fetch all anchor tags buried in that once it finds it. I would suggest two potential errors: (1) You have two divs with the id TargetDiV on the same page or (2) You've made another typo in either your html of javascript that's further screwing things up.

Comment: I reviewed my code once more, and it turns out there really was another typo. I've learned a few lessons today. Thanks Ipd. Thanks everyone!